# swift: dictionary variable passed by reference before being initialized

Tags: dictionary, swift, ios8

I am initializing a dictionary in swift, then using in if condition block.

```
    var attr:Dictionary<String,AnyObject>;

    if !isLoading {
        attr["variableSender"] = self  //Error here         
        attr["variableMode"] = "get"
        ...

    }
```

and I am getting error - Variable 'attr' passed by reference before begin initialized.

I have also tried initalizing dictionary

```
var attr:[String:AnyObject]
```

1) Why is this happening & how to resolve it. I also tried to put () brackets at the end. Solution?

2) Is there any explicit constructor for dictionary.

I am following this guide 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-XID_180

```
airports["LHR"] = "London Heathrow"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your declaration to

```
var attr = [String : AnyObject]()
```

This will initialise an empty mutable dictionary.

Comment: Update your question to show exactly what you have typed